# Integral constant is too large (CS1021) - How to put 1000 extremely big (70+ digits) integers in an array?

Tags: c#

I'm using the software SharpDevelop (C#).

I've created a list of integers (array) like this:

```
int[] name = new int[number-of-elements]{elements-separated-by-commas}
```

In the `{}` I would like to put 1000 integers, some with over 70 digits.

But when I do that I get the following error:

`Integral constant is too large (CS1021).`

So how do I solve this problem?

Comment: int in C# is only a 32-bit type, capable of storing numbers up to 2^31-1 ~ 2 billion. Even if you use long, you can still only store to about 19 decimal digits

Comment: What do those numbers represent? It looks like you can use `string` instead.

Comment: I think string representation is a viable alternative. It is anyway impossible to use those numbers in any calculations without implementing them manually. But if the numbers don't have that many **significant digits**, then a double is an alternative.

Comment: @JoriO: Unfortunately all their digits are significant. I cannot just round them.

Comment: @ataravati: I am not sure what a "string" is... Is it just a chain of characters in which we can't make mathematical operations? I need to perform multiplications (only by 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8) on my big numbers.

Comment: Yes, if you need to perform mathematical operations you can't use `string`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error does not mean that you have too many integers in your array. It means that one of the integers is larger than the maximum value representable in an `int` in C#, i.e. above `2,147,483,647`.

If you need representation of 70-digit numbers, use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
BigInteger[] numbers = new[] {
    BigInteger.Parse("1234567890123456789012345678")
,   BigInteger.Parse("2345678901234567890123456789")
,   ...
};
```

Comment: In the question it was said, that some numbers have over 70 digits. Your solution doesn't really solve the problem.

Comment: And the particular error the OP is getting does indicate a constant that does not fit into *any* integer type, not merely one that does not fit into `int`.

Comment: Maybe [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Sorry but I didn't quite understand how to use this "BigInteger". SharpDevelop is showing two errors: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'BigInteger[]' (CS0029)  and The type or namespace name 'BigInteger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

Comment: @user50746 You need to use `BigInteger`, not `int` (see the answer). `BigInteger` requires `using System.Numerics` at the top.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I typed "using System.Numerics;" at the top, but now I get this error: The type or namespace name 'Numerics' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you using an assembly reference?) (CS0234)

Comment: @user50746 You need to add `System.Numerics` module to your project.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Ok, so I went in Project > Add reference > System.Numerics. But now the error that SharpDevelop is showing is: Cannot implicitly convert type 'int[]' to 'BigInteger[]' (CS0029). The error comes from line 23 which is: BigInteger[] numbers = new[] {2,4,6,12,24,36,48,60,120,180,240,360,720}; (I've just put the first few numbers just to see if it works)

Comment: @user50746 You cannot use plain numbers like that, you need to use `BigInteger.Parse("numberString")` or `new BigInteger(number)` for each item on your list.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Oh, I see. But then it's impossible since it would be way too time consuming to write "BigInteger.Parse("numberString")" for each of the 1000 integers...

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I just tried it for the first 20 integers. It didn't even work. SharpDevelop is displaying this error: "No best type found for implicitly-typed array (CS0826)". It concerns some other other BigInteger number lists that I created and that I wanted to be empty : "BigInteger[] name = new[] {};" (I didn't put any number in the "{}" because I wanted this list to be empty)

Comment: @user50746 In situations when you do not have any values in an array, you need to provide the type explicitly: `BigInteger[] name = new BigInteger[] {}`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Okay, one final (I think) question: how do I create an array with 1000 "0"s (a thousand zeros) as values? Because when I try to use the array with no values that you just showed me I get this error on a separate window: "Unhandled exception - An exception of type System.IndexOutOfRangeException was thrown - Index was outside the bounds of the array" which is relative to this line: BigInteger[] name = new BigInteger[] {} (the array which is supposed to have only zeros as values)

Comment: @user50746 When you do this `BigInteger[] name = new BigInteger[] {}` you get zero elements in the array, not an array of zeros. You can get a zero by using `BigInteger.Zero`. If you need an array of 1000 of zeros, you could init it like this: `BigInteger[] name = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => BigInteger.Zero).ToArray();`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: SharpDevelop is displaying this error: "The name 'Enumerable' does not exist in the current context (CS0103)." It is relative to the thing you just gave me: BigInteger[] name = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).Select(i => BigInteger.Zero).ToArray();

Comment: @user50746 Import `System.Linq` to access `Enumerable`. In general, you can look up which module to import by checking the online documentation.

Comment: Yes, my program works! Thank you very much dasblinkenlight for all the help you provided me.

Answer (score 3):

From .Net Framework 4.0 Microsoft introduced `System.Numerics.dll` which contains a `BigInteger` structure which can represents an arbitrarily large signed integer. for more information you can refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
        BigInteger[] name =
        {
            BigInteger.Parse("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"),
            BigInteger.Parse("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999")
        };
```

for older versions of framework you can use `IntX` library. you can obtain the package either from Nuget with `Intall-Package IntX` command or https://intx.codeplex.com/

```
        IntX[] name =
        {
            IntX.Parse("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999"),
            IntX.Parse("9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999")
        };
```

other problem is the biggest integer literal you can define in c# is `ulong` with max value of `18,446,744,073,709,551,615` (larger values leads to compile error), which is obviously not enough in your case, easy solution would be to use `BigInteger.Parse` or in case of `IntX` library `IntX.Parse`.