# What is the Max value for 'float'?

Tags: c#, variables, compiler-errors, minimax

When I check the value of "float.MaxValue" I'm getting:

3.402823E+38

which is:

```
340,282,300,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

Then why when I'm trying to set a much smaller value into a float variable:

```
float myValue = 1234567890123456789024;
```

then I get an error message:

> Integral constant is too large

This value is MUCH smaller then "3.402823E+38", so why am I getting an error for it?

Comment: @Camilo - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26316018/integral-constant-is-too-large-cs1021-how-to-put-1000-extremely-big-70-dig is very different question (this is likely duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519743/why-is-the-f-required-when-declaring-floats seem to be good choice explaining why, also will need to add integres there)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov How is it a different question if it's the same compilation error?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto OP is looking to get `float` and not to handle large integers. Since you can't really mix float/double with BigInteger there is not much value to constructing constant as `BigInteger` to use in float/double computations down the road.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Except the OP *is* declaring a `BigInteger` rather than a `float`. I would agree if I at least saw a `.1` there. There's nothing in the post that says the OP wants a non-integral data-type

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't see how `float myValue = …` can be considered as attempt to use `BigInteger`... but that's my interpretation of the post. At any rate with two duplicates and an answer OP should have enough information to resolve their problem.

Answer (score 9):

Most *Numeric* types have a `MaxValue`  Field

[Single.MaxValue Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Represents the largest possible value of Single. This field is
>   constant.

Which equates to

```
public const float MaxValue = 3.402823E+38;
```

However in this case, you need to put use `f` suffix to specify a type of a numerical literal, otherwise it will interpret it as an integral type (on a cascading scale of max range up to `uint64`).

```
float myValue = 1234567890123456789024f;
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[Value types table (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types-table)

[Compiler Error CS1021](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1021)

> Integral constant is too large
>
> A value represented by an integer literal is greater than
>   UInt64.MaxValue.

[UInt64.MaxValue Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uint64.maxvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Represents the largest possible value of UInt64. This field is
>   constant.

```
public const ulong MaxValue = 18446744073709551615;
```